# undefined method `formats=' for ... Controller:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, undefined

I'm trying to send a 'delete' request with rspec. The problem is that I'm getting the following error :

> undefined method `formats=' for Admin::CountriesController:Class

Here is my code :

```
describe 'Admin user deletion button' do
  def sign_in(user)
    user.confirm!
    visit '/login'
    fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'user_password', with: user.password
    click_button 'login_submit'
  end

  it 'should display an error' do
      @controller = Admin::UsersController
      @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)

      sign_in @admin
      delete :delete, user_id: -1
    end
end
```

EDIT : Here is the full error :

> 1) Admin user deletion button with existing user should display an
>   error
>        Failure/Error: delete :delete, user_id: -1
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method 'formats=' for Admin::UsersController:Class
>        # ./spec/controllers/admin_user_deletion_spec.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in '

EDIT 2 : Here is the controller code :

```
module Admin
# Controller for users admin panel
class UsersController < AdminController
  include UserHelper

  before_action :actual_user

  def users
    @users = User.normals.page(params[:users_page])
    @admins = User.admins.page(params[:admins_page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :new_user
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)

    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = "L'utilisateur #{user.name} a bien été creé"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "L'utilisateur n'a pas pu être créé"
    end
    redirect_to action: :users
  end

  def edit
    render :edit_user
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params) && @user.confirm!
      flash[:notice] = "L'utilisateur #{@user.name} a bien été mis à jour"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "L'utilisateur #{@user.name} n'a pas pu être mis à jour"
    end
    redirect_to action: :users
  end

  def delete
    name = @user.name

    if @user.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "L'utilisateur #{name} a bien été supprimé"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "L'utilisateur #{name} n'a pas pu être supprimé"
    end
    redirect_to action: :users
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params[:user].delete(:password) if params[:user][:password].blank?
    params.require(:user).permit!
  end

  def actual_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Please include a stacktrace in your question.

Comment: What line of your controller is it bombing on?  We need to see that action.

Comment: There is no stacktrace or specified line for controller. Let's see the updated question to get the "full" error.

Comment: Show us the relevant code of your controller please.

Comment: Can you post the FULL controller code?

Comment: Didn't think I had to, just did it.

Comment: Provided code of controller is `Admin::UsersController`, but the error seems to have something to do with `Admin::CountriesController`.

Comment: Your explanation for the test says "admin user deletion button", which imho would imply deleting a user? Yet you test against the `Admin::CountriesController`, and that is where the error takes place. Then you show us the `UserController`??? There would be some assignment like `x.formats=` in the `delete` action in the `Admin::CountriesController`, and we need to see that line to be able to help you.

Comment: Indeed there was a misstype in the test, but it's updated and still provide the same error (but with UsersController instead of CountriesController).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *Never get involved in a land war in Asia.*
2. *Never go against a Sicilian when death is on the line.*
3. *Never confuse a controller spec and a feature spec.*

Controller specs make assumptions about their prerequisites--feature specs don't. You have confused the two, a common mistake.

You should never use `visit` in a controller spec. Instead, pass the request parameters and (if necessary) session data in the call to the action itself.

As to why your request fails, consider the error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'formats=' for Admin::UsersController:Class
```

This is because you have redefined the controller instance variable and assigned it the controller *class*, instead of a controller *instance*. Instead, leave the controller instance variable alone and allow RSpec to call the action on the instance.

If you need further convincing, check the return value of `@controller.respond_to?(:formats=)` within the context of a spec; in your version this returns `false`, but in a standard controller spec (e.g. one created by the RSpec generator), this will return `true`.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.. I too have a scenario like@controller = Admin::UsersController . I dont have rspec instead have Minitests  . Could you please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: @Jasmine I'm not sure if this is still relevant. I've encountered a similar issue, which eventually boils down to my source controller not inheriting from `ApplicationController`